# Excessive memory usage in C++ OpenCV mouse point code

Tags: c++, memory, opencv, mouse, point

Hello everyone and thank you for many useful topics on stackoverflow –they helped me a lot since I’m very inexperienced in programming. As part of a project for university I’m trying to implement a perspective correction on business cards to prepare them for OCR in C++ using OpenCV libraries. I found the automated corner detection via Canny and Hough to be somewhat unreliable depending on the particular card and the background so I would like to implement a way to select the corners manually for now.

I found the following code (OpenCVSelect.cpp) by the user ajithsri on sourceforge ( http://sourceforge.net/p/opencvselmov/code/ci/master/tree/ ), which is exactly what I needed. However after playing around with it for some time it suddenly crashed making me suspicious. Looking at the task manager while clicking around and moving points I noticed that a huge amount of memory is used without being released until the program crashes.

Now, like I said I am really inexperienced when it comes to programming and I couldn’t find what’s wrong with the code so please forgive me if the solution is obvious for you.
I would really appreciate if someone could help me with the memory problem in the code so I could use it for my project.

Thank you!

(OpenCV libraries and black.jpg is needed)

Comment: You should use cv2 api http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/core.html. Specificly use Mat instead of IplImage.

Comment: Writing your own perspective transform should not prove to be that difficult. OpenCV provides quite helpful tutorials on mouse interaction. If you have the four corner points, you can use cv::warpPerspective to fix the image (and again, a lot of tutorials on this can be found)

Comment: Thank you! I actually have the last part with warpPerspective and it alone works fine. I just need to find a way to set the corner points without generating memory leaks. I guess there's no way around the tutorials then!

Answer (score 1):

Here is one of the problems. You are cloning a huge number of images and only releasing the last one.

```
void showImage(){
    IplImage *img2=img0;
    for(int j=0;j<nop;j++){     
        img2 = cvCloneImage(img2);
              ...
              for(int k=j+1;k<nop;k++){
                 img2 = cvCloneImage(img2);
                 ...
               }
     }
     ...
     cvReleaseImage(&img2);
```

Remove all those calls to `cvCloneImage()` and instead change

```
         IplImage *img2=img0;
```

to

```
         IplImage *img2=cvCloneImage(img0);
```

That code is so poorly written there are probably numerous other problems.

`findImg()` has a similar leak to above.

Comment: Thank you very much! I also got the feeling that this is poorly written and that there must be a better solution. However I'm happy for every code snipped I find on the internet so I don't want to comlain or anything.

I will try and correct what you said. If there are still numerous other problems I guess it's best to start over with a tutorial for me. Thanks again!

Comment: I just wanted to thank you again! I changed everything to cv2 and fixed what you said and it works now using around 8 Mb of memory instead of adding up to 1,800 Mb with every click before crashing :)